# What is the best way to access/reference a dynamically generated object that has linkage in the stage?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

In actionscript 3, what is the best way to access/reference a dynamically generated object that has linkage in the stage which is the type of Movie Clip, where the dynamically placed object(s) are located in the specific frame (one keyframe) and accessed via custom function from timeline code in a long frame?

And also, what is the appropriate code to remove child/object that are dynamically placed Object/CLass name (which is being extended from library) from the stage (main timeline)?

Comment: Are you writing your code in .as classes or in frames?

Comment: Hi @Pier. The code is in frames.

Comment: You should stop writing code in frames and start using classes if you want to find "the best way". Then you will be able to pass references of your instances between classes and such

Comment: Thanks @Pier. I think I should base the creation and removal of dynamic clips for the class instantiated in the constructor in an empty clip placed on the stage.

Comment: You don't need to put clips in an empty clip to reference it. You can create your objects inside an array.